# How would you build a bill splitting app using Lightning? Does one already exist?

Tags: lightning-network, btcpay

How would you build a bill splitting app (20+ people) on Lightning? Does one already exist? Setting up a BTCPay Server shop seems like over engineering.

This was asked by fulmolightning on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/fulmolightning/status/1589940925567930368?s=20&t=mBM9tiWUVdxCd34OizIPGg).